# Why does cin.getline assign to character array but using '=' will not?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, variable-assignment, getline

For instance, if I am getting student names from a user and use `cin.getline(student.name, 50);` I can assign student names. I cannot explicitly assign a student name via `student.name = "John Doe";` since you cannot just copy an array over, but why does this work when i use the getline function? What is the difference? Isn't `getline()` collecting a character array and then copying it to `studnet.name` anyway?

For clarification, I'm asking why I can use `cin.getline(student.name, 50)` to assign a student name but not `stuent.name = "John Doe"` and what is the difference between the 2 methods (why the `getline()` works and the direct assignment does not work).

Comment: Is `name` a `char` array? If so, arrays are not assignable, so you cannot write `arrayname = "blah";`. Also, unless you have a very good reason not to, you should be using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: @Praetorian Your comment seems a fitting answer, why not make it so?

Comment: I'm not asking how to assign `char name[50] = "John Doe"`, I'm asking why `cin.getline(student.name, 50)` works while direct assigning doesnt. In the end I'm asking what the difference is between the 2.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee `basic_istream::getline` takes a *pointer* to the char array and writes to whatever location that pointer points to. The language defines an implicit conversion from an array to a pointer to the first element of the array, so when you say `cin.getline(student.name, 50)` a pointer to the first element of the `name` member gets passed to `getline`. Direct assignment to an array doesn't work because it is not defined in C or C++.

Comment: :D Could you update your answer please? What if my student header file's name is also a pointer? such as `char* name;`, would I be able to use both `getline()` and direct assignment?

Comment: @Praetorian irrespective of whether it's a pointer or an array, `getline` would assign char by char into name & not in a single assignment.  If the pointer is assigned to directly inside getline - then that would be a local copy of the pointer which is changed. The calling code would never see what string the pointer has been assigned. getline has to copy the string char by char into the memory pointed to by the pointer. If you want trying coding your own getline equivalent and see what happens.

Comment: @user93353 I never said anything about `getline` being able to do the assignment to the pointer in a single statement, of course it must be done character by character. And I don't understand why you're talking about `getline` re-assigning the pointer locally; my comment clearly says *writes to whatever location that pointer points to*

Comment: @Praetorian - I think that's what Howdy_McGee has interpreted your answer to mean - not your fault, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the parameter list of the [istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) function, `istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );`, you will notice that it takes your variable, `student.name`, as a pointer.  This allows getline to write directly to the memory location of your c-string.

edit: see Praetorian's answer in the comments for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Ha, did you just summarize @Praetorian's comment?

Comment: oh, I didn't see his comment, I'll give him credit.  I remember wondering the same thing last semester when I learned about cin.getline though, haha.

Answer (score 2):

See the following C FAQ questions - http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html and http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arraylval.html.

I am assuming here that `name` is a `char name[something]`.

If you want to assign, use the `std::string` type instead of a `char array`

Change your

```
char name[50];
```

to

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

... ...

    string name;

... ...
```

Now you can use `=` like you want to.

`getline` works because internally it would do something like this

- read one char.
- assign to name[0]
- read next char.
- assign to name[1].

and so on.

Comment: right I understand that if I want to use strings, but using getline will assign whatever it got from the user into the `char name[50]` of the student class and my question is why that works and direct assigning doesnt.

Comment: `getline` is assigning each character separately (in a loop), just like the `strcpy` function would do.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - Did you check the 2 FAQ Links in my answer?. That will explain why char arrays cannot be directly assigned. `getline` works because it isn't do a direct assignment. It's doing a char by char assignment, just like `std::string` does.

Comment: I did but do not feel it firmly answers the question I asked. I feel @Praetorian hit the answer square on the head with his comment.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - not Praetorian's answer is not correct. Pointers can be assigned directly, but that's not relevant in this case. If the pointer is assigned to directly inside getline - then that would be a local copy of the pointer which is changed. Your code would never see what string the pointer has been assigned. getline has to copy the string char by char into the memory pointed to by the pointer.